# Annotation parameter: explicit vs. implicit String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, annotations

Why does the second Test in my scenario has the syntax error `The value for annotation attribute SuppressWarnings.value must be an array initializer` on the `SuppressWarnings` line?

```
public class AnnotationTest {
    private static final String supUnused = "unused";
    private static final String supDeprecation = "deprecation";
    private static final String[] suppressArray = { "unused", "deprecation" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test 1
        @SuppressWarnings( { supUnused, supDeprecation } )
        int a = new Date().getDay();

        // Test 2
        @SuppressWarnings(suppressArray)    // syntax error
        int b = new Date().getDay();
    }
}
```

If you're passing the parameters as two single constants, it works.
If you're passing it with an array constant, there is a syntax error.

What is the explanation for this error?

Comment: [SuppressWarnings documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) might helps

Comment: @RafaEl: Thanks for the documentation link! The point is, that I already know, for what you have to use `SupressWarnings` ;)

Comment: yes of course I know that you know that. but.. okay, I have no idea why I gave you the link :D

Comment: @Downvoter: please explain!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you're passing it with an array constant, there is a syntax error.

Annotation arguments must be constant.

The `suppressArray` is declared `final`, but this only means that you can not reassign the `suppressArray` variable with another array reference. You can still change the `suppressArray`'s content, e.g.

```
suppressArray[0] = "someOtherString";
```

In your first example you use an array initializer inline.

```
@SuppressWarnings( { supUnused, supDeprecation } )
```

Therefore no other class can obtain a reference to it and thus can not change the array's content.

At least a look at the [JLS 9.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7) gives a detailed explanation.

The annotation arguements are name value pairs where `T` is the type of the name value pair while `V` is the value:

> - If T is a primitive type or String, and V is a constant expression (§15.28).
> - V is not null.
> - If T is Class, or an invocation of Class, and V is a class literal (§15.8.2).
> - If T is an enum type, and V is an enum constant.

and

> An ElementValueArrayInitializer is similar to a normal array initializer (§10.6), except that annotations are permitted in place of expressions.

Comment: Great and plausible answer! I was struggling with `must be an array initializer`. Because, it is in fact an array initializer, but in a different way... And your explanation shows up, why it is not possible to pass an array with a reference. Thank you!