# Confused with compiling error with Java annotation field types

Tags: java

I get confused about the compiler error message when working with Java annotations. The following code is an example. In short, I creates a annotation type `CustomAnnotation` containing fields in String or in String[], and I annotates a method and fills the field values with `static final` variables.

Note the the field types follow the [JLS 9.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1).

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface CustomAnnotation
{
    String editorType() default "";
    String defaultValue() default "";
    String[] editorArgs() default {};
}

class Constants
{
    public static final String some_string = "(･ω´･ )";
    public static final String another_string = "(((ﾟДﾟ;)))";
    public static final String[] some_array = {"1", "2", "3"};
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    @CustomAnnotation(editorType=Constants.some_string,
                      defaultValue=Constants.another_string,
                      editorArgs=Constants.some_array)
    void method() {}
}
```

The String fields work fine, but surprisingly, the compiler complains about incompatible types on `editorArgs` in type String[].

```
Main.java:28: error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
                      editorArgs=Constants.some_array)
                                          ^
1 error
```

However, the following code compiles without error, but I failed to figure out what's going wrong.

```
editorArgs={"1", "2", "3"})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252475/annotation-parameter-explicit-vs-implicit-string-array

Comment: Thanks Koekje. The post provides a good explanation for this situation. The message `incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String` might be misleading.